# how to operate AVPlayerViewController screen player Controls?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm new to ios app development and dont know working with AVPLayerViewController ?

Can you please tell me how to catch `done` event atleast

And Apples documentation is not so great for this AVPVC

I've written small code and its working?

```
            let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerController.player = mediaPlayer  // this is AVPlayer with item
            self.addChildViewController(playerController)

            self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
            playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
```

but dont know how to control previous and next buttons and done button also in the view controller Please help or provide some documentation.

Comment: Working with `AVPlayerViewController` most of the time is working with `AVPlayer` or (in case you need sort of playlist) `AVQueuePlayer`. [Apple has great resources about the topic](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/). Specifically, take a look at [Playback](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW1) chapter of [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html)